# on varnish, how can i see how many requests to each server are sent?

Tags: varnish, round-robin

I'd like to see how many requests varnish is sending to each backend via round-robin director.
i haven't found out how so far. thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get this numbers from varnish directly, but if youre using round-robin director I'd guess the traffic to each backend will be nearly the 1/n of total ammount where n is number of backends. This is true only if backends all healthy and not skipped from round.

You can still get theese stattistics from backend access log or server-status page or similar, depending on http daemon used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on the varnish log file, but you should be able to use varnishlog and sample it.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/varnishlog

The sample, should give you an idea of the distribution.

Another option, would be to do a netstat and see how many connections are open to the background server.

-daniel